# Does Nexus 6 sold by AT&T differ from one sold on Google Play in any way?

Tags: att, nexus-6

What are the differences between the Google Play Edition of the Nexus 6 and the AT&T version? Does it have any AT&T "bloatware"? Will its updates come from AT&T instead of Google? Is it locked to AT&T's network?

Answer (score 2):

Nexus 6 models sold via AT&T are reported to have these differences ([source 1](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/11/19/atts-nexus-6-does-indeed-have-the-globe-on-the-back-plus-a-globe-and-jingle-on-the-boot-screen-because-att/), [source 2](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/11/20/atts-nexus-6-is-sim-locked-checks-mobile-hotspot-subscription-status-for-tethering-and-has-the-carriers-ringtones/), [source 3](http://www.ubergizmo.com/2014/11/atts-nexus-6-will-come-preloaded-with-bloatware/)):

- It is SIM locked to AT&T
- There is an AT&T logo on the back of the phone
- The phone displays an AT&T branded boot animation/sound on startup
- It performs a check to ensure your current plan allows tethering before it will allow it to be activated
- Several AT&T ringtones have been added
- After the initial setup, if an AT&T SIM is inserted/activated, it will download and install several AT&T apps automatically. These can evidently be removed, without root.

It has been speculated that updates will still be received on-time because the AT&T extras are on a separate partition (mounted at `/oem`), but this has not been confirmed, to my knowledge. With root, you can remove the ringtones/boot animation from the `/oem` partition. You would need to obtain an unlock code in order to use it on a different network.